# NameError: name 'msg' is not defined. Discord

Tags: python, discord

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
test = randint(1000, 99999)

def check(m):
    return m.content == f'{captcha}' and m.author.id == member.id

try:
    msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
    await msg.add_reaction("✅")

except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await msg.add_reaction("❌")
    await member.send('TimeOut')
    await member.kick(reason='TimeOut')
else:
    await member.send('Thank')
```

Ошибка:

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\Py\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\Users\Stanisla\Desktop\Turtle-Bot\cogs\Moderation.py", line 135,
> in on_member_join
> await msg.add_reaction("❌") UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется строка `await msg.add_reaction("❌")`  у вас должна быть до `except:` по логике.
В случае исключения по таймауту у вас в `msg` не успевает ничего записаться, из-за этого ошибка.